# Swiper js - timeline section

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I made a timeline section using swiper js.
When I swipe left or right my timeline is very synchronous and when I move the swiper the dates diverge. The new date overtakes the old date, etc.

Do you have any idea how to modify this timeline to make it work properly?
It should be in sync with each other and run smoothly
The carousel is faster than the top carousel

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/u8sLjbxn/1/`
```

I have been struggling to create a timeline, but it is not working properly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: All code is available on jsfiddle